# Running html file from vs code does not include drive paths

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

When i try to run vs code html files for a testfile, the run command goes to "testfile.html/" instead of "file:///E:/1%20work/Tests/testpage.html", how do i fix this?

Comment: I think somehow VSCode must have a something configured for opening files in a _server_ context, which is the reason why it's going to testfile.html/ (btw the configuration seems to beblank). Instead, try opening the file _from the browser directly_ (File/Open/...)

Comment: I know i can open the file directly from web browser but is there any way to directly run it from vs code?

Comment: have you tried simply from your file explorer ?